# scikit RandomForestClassifier - real results not matching prediction score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to machine learning and I am trying to classify text using a scikit RandomForestClassifier. The problem I have is that my test data results don't match the sklearn classification report. The training set has about 25k samples, about 25% of which are tagged 1 and 75% 0. I have a an additional test set of 1k which I am using to test after training.

**# Train**

```
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=40, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents).toarray()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=0)

    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(
    n_jobs=-1, bootstrap=False, n_estimators=200, random_state=0)

    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

               precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.98      0.99      0.98      4231
       1       0.95      0.90      0.92       883

accuracy                           0.97      5114
```

**# Test**

```
df = pandas.read_csv(input_file, header=None)
df.columns = ["data", "target"]

df, y = df.data, df.target

test_documents = []
for body in range(0, len(df)):
    document = str(df[body])
    test_documents.append(document)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_documents).toarray()
prediction = pd.DataFrame(classifier.predict(X))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.89      0.87      0.88       856
       1       0.38      0.42      0.40       154
```

Comment: 1. for the test dataset, you do not need to `fit_transform`. 2. check if your model is overfitting

Comment: @Mr_U4913 Thank you. Follow up q: 1) How should I re-write that line? 2. How can I test for overfitting in my model?

Comment: 1. `transform` instead of `fit_transform` 2. if test accuracy is close to the training accuracy, then your model fit just right. if test acc is much lower than train acc, then your model is overfitting. if test acc is better than train acc, your model is underfitting and train a more complex model

Comment: just elaborate on what Mr_U4913 said: in your "#test" code, transform your data by using the existing vectorizer you made in the "#train" code...and call the transform method, not the fit_transform

Comment: This cannot be real code. It's called a random _forest_ classifier.

Comment: Two other things to note: `max_features=40` seems pretty low for tfidf, this means it will only encode the 40 most common words in your dataset. You can inspect the `.vocabulary_` property to see which words are encoded. Note that with many more features, you might want to have a look at RF's `max_features` parameter. Second, you use random forest without a `max_depth`, this means it will let the decision trees grow extremely specific and will likely overfit, usually values between ~3 and ~20 are ok (just run a few experiments).

Comment: @Swier Thanks a lot, this is really useful. Before I posted here, I did a bit of a programmers rain-dance, where one wrong line of code was producing random results, and I kept tweaking every parameter hoping to see a positive effect. I shall now start applying logic again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping Mr_U4913 was going to add this but I will instead.

try this for your test code:

### test

```
df = pandas.read_csv(input_file, header=None)
df.columns = ["data", "target"]

df, y = df.data, df.target

test_documents = []
for body in range(0, len(df)):
    document = str(df[body])
    test_documents.append(document)
X = vectorizer.transform(test_documents).toarray()  #here is where change is!
prediction = pd.DataFrame(classifier.predict(X))
```

Note the change...we now use the transform method for the vectorizer. I am assuming you can put this test code into the same file as your training code so that your vectorizer object is still alive.

The reason you use transform and *not* fit_transform is that you have trained your model using the vectorizer fitted with a particular vocabulary and during testing new words may appear.  Using the existing vectorizer will ignore these new words/combos and will serve to keep your tdif vectors harmonized.  As opposed to using fit_transform which recreates, possibly quite differently, your vectorizer which will have small/large differences.

edit: you may wish to try a logistic classifier as well...sometimes it gives decent results on this sort of data.

Comment: Thank you very much. My test results are now much closer to the train test results. BUT when I merge my test results to a csv and inspect them manually, I can see that of 148 predicted 1's only 25 are correct. I must still be doing something wrong.

Comment: your saga will continue...not finding the *best* solution doesn't necessarily mean you're doing something *wrong*! it also very much depends on what the expectations of your model are. Pretend that there were only 25 1's in the test set...you would have successfully isolated all of them (say the task was to throw examples away with the 0 label...you've gone from 1000 to 148...for human review or whatever).

Comment: My problem was a typo further in the code which I didn't post, and it simply merged the results wrong. So the model is now performing about 90% accurate and I'm pretty happy with that. Now to compare a logistic classifier... cheers!